# Terraform Template_file and metadata_startup_script variables not working as expected

Tags: terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I have gce resource being created and bootstrapped with a startup script but seeing some weird issues with variables.
I have gce resource being created and bootstrapped with a startup script but seeing some weird issues with variables.
Created TF resources as per:

```
data "template_file" "init" {
  template = "${file("../../../Boomi/linux/test.sh")}"
  vars = {
    platform            = var.platform
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "atom_instance" {
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  metadata_startup_script = "${data.template_file.init.rendered}"
...
test.sh script
#!/bin/bash
#set -e
echo "platform:${platform}"
if [ -z $platform ] ; then
  echo "parameter needed!"
if [ -n $platform ] ; then
  echo "parameter provided!"
fi
```

In the Serial Console output I got the following after the bash script was run:

```
Jan 15 20:44:25 debian google_metadata_script_runner[471]: startup-script: platform:gcp
Jan 15 20:44:25 debian google_metadata_script_runner[471]: startup-script: parameter needed!
Jan 15 20:44:25 debian google_metadata_script_runner[471]: startup-script: parameter provided!
Jan 15 20:44:25 debian google_metadata_script_runner[471]: startup-script: completed
Jan 15 20:44:25 debian google_metadata_script_runner[471]: startup-script exit status 0
```

This makes no sense as $platform variable is set so wouldn't expect  "parameter needed!" in the output.
It seems like the null check  is not working?
if [ -z $platform ] ; then
Any ideas?

Comment: Where was the platform variable set? To me it seems you are just echoing what was previously rendered with the data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues I can spot...

#### unclosed if statement

Your code

```
if [ -z $platform ] ; then
  echo "parameter needed!"
if [ -n $platform ] ; then
  echo "parameter provided!"
fi
```

You can have two if statements like:

```
if [ -z $platform ] ; then
  echo "parameter needed!"
fi
if [ -n $platform ] ; then
  echo "parameter provided!"
fi
```

another option is to use the `elif` to make

```
if [ -z $platform ] ; then
  echo "parameter needed!"
elif [ -n $platform ] ; then
  echo "parameter provided!"
fi
```

#### there is no `$platform` variable

This is a template file, if you need a variable you need to add that code:
`export platform=${platform}`

or just replace all the `$platform` with `${platform}` to make the replacement

---

In general you want to troubleshoot these issues by outputting your code and run the script in isolation, that will save you a lot of time so you don't have to generate resources
Something like:

```
output "file" {
    value = data.template_file.init.rendered
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right on all points.
I did miss out the fi then added it later, was just some blind debug statements.
Regarding the variables, I missed out the curly brackets for some reason.
The output is a good tip, useful for  debugging.
Thank you